# How to access Keycloak's AuthorizationContext from inside a PermissionEvaluator?

Tags: spring-boot, permissions, keycloak

I'm trying to achieve fine grained permissions in my application using spring boot and Keycloak.

As such i would like to be using the following annotiations:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('myResource', 'myScope')")
```

So I have implemented the following:

```java
@Slf4j
public class KeycloakPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        // This should probably never be the case but let's check it anyways
        if (authentication == null) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'authentication' argument (null)");
            return false;
        }
        // targetDomainObject will be the resourceName.
        // It can be null in case we only want to check permissions for a specific scope else it should be a String
        if (targetDomainObject != null && !(targetDomainObject instanceof String)) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'targetDomainObject' argument ({})", targetDomainObject.getClass().getName());
            return false;
        }
        // permission will be the scopeName.
        // It can be null in case we only want to check permissions for a specific resource else it should be a String
        if (permission != null && !(permission instanceof String)) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'permission' argument ({})", permission.getClass().getName());
            return false;
        }

        return hasPermission((KeycloakPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal(), (String) targetDomainObject, (String) permission);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        // This should probably never be the case but let's check it anyways
        if (authentication == null) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'authentication' argument (null)");
            return false;
        }
        // targetId needs to be set else we should be using hasPermission(Authentication, Object, Object)
        // It will be used to build the resourceName
        if (!(targetId instanceof String)) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'targetId' argument ({}). Did you mean to use hasPermission(resource, scope) ?", targetId == null ? "null" : targetId.getClass().getName());
            return false;
        }
        // targetType will be used to build the resourceName
        if (targetType == null) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'targetType' argument (null)");
            return false;
        }
        // permission will be the scopeName.
        // It can be null in case we only want to check permissions for a specific resource else it should be a String
        if (permission != null && !(permission instanceof String)) {
            log.warn("Permission denied because of illegal 'permission' argument ({})", permission.getClass().getName());
            return false;
        }

        String resourceName = String.format("%s/%s", targetType, targetId);
        return hasPermission((KeycloakPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal(), resourceName, (String) permission);
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(KeycloakPrincipal principal, String resourceName, String scopeName) {
        AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = principal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getAuthorizationContext();

        if (resourceName == null) {
            if (scopeName == null) {
                log.warn("Permission denied because both resourceName and scopeName are null.");
                return false;
            }
            return authorizationContext.hasScopePermission(scopeName);
        } else if (scopeName == null) {
            return authorizationContext.hasResourcePermission(resourceName);
        } else {
            return authorizationContext.hasPermission(resourceName, scopeName);
        }
    }

}
```

However that doesn't seem to work. `authorizationContext` ends up being `null`.
Here is what the Authentication object looks like in `hasPermission`
[image: Authetication object]

Here is my SecurityConfig

```java
@Slf4j
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> {
            log.warn("401 Unauthorized while processing " + request.getRequestURI(), authException);
            response.sendError(401, "Unauthorized");
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                // Public
                .antMatchers(
                    "/v3/api-docs/**",
                    "/swagger-ui.html",
                    "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                // Private
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

and my method security config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new KeycloakPermissionEvaluator());
        expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

And the Keycloak config:

```json
{
  "realm": "${env.KEYCLOAK_REALM}",
  "auth-server-url": "${env.KEYCLOAK_AUTH_SERVER}",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "enable-cors": true,
  "resource": "my-server",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "${env.KEYCLOAK_SECRET}"
  },
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {
    "enforcement-mode": "PERMISSIVE",
    "paths": [
      {
        "name": "Default",
        "path": "*/*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This seems related to [KEYCLOAK-12260](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12260)

I have added a controller to showcase my issue:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest autowWiredRequest;

    @GetMapping
    public String hello(Principal principal) {
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken principal1 = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) this.autowWiredRequest.getUserPrincipal();
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken principal2 = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getUserPrincipal();
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken principal3 = (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        boolean allTheSame = (principal1 == principal2 && principal2 == principal3);

        KeycloakPrincipal<?> keycloakPrincipal = (KeycloakPrincipal<?>) principal1.getPrincipal();
        KeycloakSecurityContext keycloakSecurityContext = keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext();
        AuthorizationContext authorizationContext = keycloakSecurityContext.getAuthorizationContext();

        return authorizationContext == null ? "null" : "OMG we're there!";
    }
}
```

This is what the debug looks like:
[image]

And here is something interesting also: there seems to be another SecurityContext that contains all that I want [image]

Comment: Your security config is missing. Hard to guess what your Authentication instance will look like :/ I know this seems stupid, but have you just tried to set a break-point at beginning of your `hasPermission` implementation to inspect Authentication structure?

Comment: @ch4mp thanks. I added the Security related configs. Also put the screenshot of the of the structure of the object using a break point.

Comment: Added some more information based on my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a lot of digging and some help from colleagues, finding out the fact some objects have multiple beans lead us to [that page](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.adoc#avoid-double-bean-registration)

So adding the following lines to the SecurityContext made the AuthorizationContext available.

```java
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakPreAuthActionsFilterRegistrationBean(
            KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilterBean(
            KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean keycloakSecurityContextRequestFilterBean(
        KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

Now what I hoped to have working with this is not working yet but at least my question here is answered.

EDIT: I went a bit further and encountered some more resistance. I raised an issue directly on the Keycloak Jira: [KEYCLOAK-16515](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-16515)